# pd.read_excel(C:\Users\yaswa\Downloads\"Dataset-DV.xlsx",sheet_name="ListOfOrders")while reading file it shows invalid syntax

Tags: python

```
pd.read_excel(C:\Users\yaswa\Downloads\"Dataset-DV.xlsx",sheet_name="ListOfOrders")
```

while reading file it shows invalid syntax

to read my data set without error

Comment: The entire file pathname should be inside the quotes.  But `C:\Users\yaswa\Downloads` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pd.read_excel("C:\Users\yaswa\Downloads\Dataset-DV.xlsx",sheet_name="ListOfOrders")
```